# Ansible This module requires the passlib Python library

Tags: ansible

I have tried to use ansible core module htpasswd on ubuntu and I get error

`This module requires the passlib Python library`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order task htpasswd module to work. server needs to have python-passlib package installed. This can be done via:

```
- name: Make sure we can use htpasswd module
  apt: "pkg=python-passlib state=installed"
```

Comment: It will not work on CentOS and RedHat as it uses `yum` intstead of `apt`, but idea is the same: `yum: name=python-passlib state=installed`

Comment: Like all things in technology, ansible has changed. The (now) correct way to do this is by changing the second line to `apt: pkg=python-passlib state=present`

Answer (score 12):

To install the latest version of passlib use pip

```
- name: Install latest passlib with pip
  pip: name=passlib
```

More on this you can read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-project/RlccHd39vWs/jTApXFb1CwAJ)

Comment: Thanks mate, the others don't work, probably because they are aiming at the apt package, not at the pip package which will be used by htpasswd (I assume)

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that you're using the version of `passlib` that matches the version of python you're using.

I had to install `python3-passlib` instead of `python-passlib`.

Answer (score 1):

Had same when installing metrics for the openshift3 with centos7 over ansible playbook.

Just simply run

```
yum install python-passlib
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux alpine, I had to install: `py3-passlib` on the local machine (Ansible controller) to be able to use `password_hash('bcrypt')`:

```
apk add py3-passlib
```

Installing `passlib` via pip3 did **not** allow me to use it in Ansible, I am not sure why.